# Getting VWAP volume over date and time using Bloomberg Java API

Tags: java, bloomberg

I am trying to use the open Bloomberg API to gather the VWAP volume on a specific date for a specific time range.  For example, how can I get the VWAP_VOLUME between 11AM and 11:15AM on August 27th?

Using Excel, I can use

`BDP("MSFT US Equity", "VWAP_VOLUME", "VWAP_START_TIME=11:00:00", "VWAP_END_TIME=11:15:00", "VWAP_START_DT=20120827", "VWAP_END_DT=20120827")`

Since I can do it in Excel, it stands to reason that I should be able to do the same thing in Java.  I've tried using a ReferenceDataRequest with overrides for the date and time fields.  I also tried using a HistoricalDataRequest with the overrides set on the time fields.  Neither returns with any data.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What timezone are you in? I'm in the UK and it works for me if I use 15:00 as a starting time and 15:15 as an end time (I  get 0 with your parameters), with the following elements, using a "ReferenceDataRequest":

- securities: MSFT US Equity
- fields: VWAP_VOLUME
- overrides:

  - fieldId=VWAP_START_TIME: value=15:00:00
  - fieldId=VWAP_END_TIME: value=15:15:00
  - fieldId=VWAP_START_DT: value=20120827
  - fieldId=VWAP_END_DT: value=20120827

Comment: You were right.  I need to make sure my time zones correlate properly to the symbol that I am looking at.  It is working now, thank you!